# Usage of DefaultIfEmpty combined with FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code

```
List<int> input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
int output = input.DefaultIfEmpty(-5).FirstOrDefault(x => x == 4);
```

It says to me "use the value -5 if there is no match"

Why does return this code `0`?

Comment: So what must be the output??

Comment: I think he's expecting, -5.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I expect `-5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will return `-5`when `input`is empty.

What you would like to do is

```
List<int> input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
int output = input.Where(x => x == 4).DefaultIfEmpty(-5).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, you could simplify it as stated in [Dmitry Bychenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42084790/4011717).

Comment: This is correct. I was thinking about this solution, too.

Comment: `OrDefault` at the end is redundant since the preceding `DefaultIfEmpty` handles that part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `4` if there's `Any` `4` in the `input` and `-5` otherwise:

```
List<int> input = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
int output = input.Any(x => x == 4) ? 4 : -5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're still getting a value. Try this:

```
int output = input.Where(x => x == 4).DefaultIfEmpty(-5).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope it helps!